# Create a Scheduled Task On Startup With Creds

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a script that creates 2 Scheduled Tasks. The first one "Check VM Status" at 12Am & 12Pm creates fine, but the other that I have tried to make to run on Windows start-up doesn't appear to work.

I have created the task manually in Task Scheduler with the account I enter when prompted and it works fine so I know my account has permission to create & run the on start-up.

```
$trigger1 = @(
    $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 12AM -Daily),
    $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 12PM -Daily)    
)
$trigger2 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$credential = Get-Credential
$username = $Credential.Username
$password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$vmhosts = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\VMStartup\VMHosts.bat'
$vmstart = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\VMStartup\VMStartup.bat'

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Check VM Status" -Action $vmhosts -Trigger $trigger1 -Description "Populates the VMHost CSV File" -User $username -Password $password
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "VMStart-Up Script" -Action $vmstart -Trigger $trigger2 -Description "Auto Starts VM's in the Running State from the VHHost CSV File" -User $username -Password $password
```

This is the output after running my script:

```
TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\                                              Check VM Status                   Ready
Register-ScheduledTask : Access is denied.
At C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\VMStartup\RunMe.ps1:20 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "VMStart-Up Script" -Action $vmstart ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-Schedul
   edTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Register-ScheduledTask
```

It's almost like Task Scheduler needs to be run as admin?

Answer (score 0):

I was using a non-admin run CMD to launch the ps1 file containing the above script. To fix I entered this into my .bat file:

```
Powershell start-process powershell -verb runas C:\VMStartup\RunMe.ps1
```